Error al publicar
Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de publicar una aplicación. Cuando inicio la aplicación a través de visual studio va todo genial pero cuando la publico obtento el siguiente error:

No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll'
ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el módulo
especificado.

He intentado publicar como debug y como release pero el mismo fallo todo el rato

Al publicar la aplicación me aparece tambien:

EDIT:


Y se esta agregando ese archivo???

A que te refieres con se esta agregando? En el proyecto lo tengo agregado, de hecho si lo pruebo en visual studio funciona perfectamente. Añado fotos

ninguno de esos archivos deberia ser .deploy.. hay algo raro ahi... que se ve en tu carpeta bin/debug o release???

en ambas carpetas se ven los mismos archivos pero sin el .deploy

Como estas haciendo la publicacion?? me pa que te esta faltando un paso, o estas generando un instalador o yo que se.. pero nada deberia tener un deploy atras.. salvooooooo que estes generando un instalador...

correcto, estoy generando un instalador. Es una aplicacion de escritorio de Windows

¿Qué pasos estás siguiendo para crear el instalador? ¿Y tú aplicación se funciona sin el instalador?

Si, la aplicación ejecutandola desde Iniciar de Visual Studio funciona perfectamente. Para crear el instalador en propiedades del proyecto -> Publicación

¿Cuál perfil de publicación usas tu?  En VS2022, puedo ver estas opciones: Azure, ClickOnce, Docker, Folder, y Importar.  Cuando publico un programa, normalmente uso Folder, porque tengo una aplicación separada para crear un instalador.

Acabo de añadir un foto de donde publico la aplicación. Se lo que comentas de seleccionar la opción pero desde el metodo que lo hago no aparece para indicar eso.

¿Cuál perfil eliges después de "Publicación"?

Continuemos el debate en el chat.
